# Broke git config file

Tags: git, git-config

I just pushed some files to a GitHub repo from my physical computer instead of my VM, and noticed that my name was displaying differently. So, like a fool, I edited the git config file, and changed my name and email address to match what I was using on my VM. Of course, git won't run at all now. I just get the following error when I try any git commands now;

`fatal: bad config line 1 in file /Users/<myusername>/.gitconfig`

I have the old values written down, so I can revert them that way if that's helpful, but I can't figure out how to edit that file again, as it is hidden (with good reason).

I'm on MacOS, Big Sur 11.2.2.

I used `git config --global --edit` to open the file, then used the editor in the terminal (vim?) to adjust the file.

I just reopened the file, and changed it back to what I think is the original, but still getting the fatal error. The file looks like this currently:

```
 This is Git's per-user configuration file.
[user]
# Please adapt and uncomment the following lines:
#       name = <myname>
#       email = <myname>@<myname>-mbp.lan
~                                                                                                                                                    
~                                                                               
".gitconfig" 5L, 153C
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: could you show us the output of `/Users/<myusername>/.gitconfig`?

Comment: What text editor do you use to edit files?

Comment: @KarthikNayak I edited my post to show the current output of the file

Comment: You could just remove it, and then instead of editing it by hand, use `git config` to make your changes (`git config --global user.email me@example.com`, etc).

Comment: @bk2204 I used Vim in the terminal

Comment: I think you removed the comment "#" from the first line, please add it back. Then you can re-add your changes like @larsks suggested.

Comment: Thank you @KarthikNayak That did it! I deleted the file, then recreated it with the added `#` and it seems to be working again so far. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you @larsks that was very helpful!! It seems to be working again now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed along with the comments, and the solution was to:

Add the `#` to the first line, first col of the file. I had already deleted it at this point, but recreating it entirely seems to have done the trick.

The steps I followed were:

1. `rm .gitconfig`
2. `touch .gitconfig`
3. `vim .gitconfig`
4. `i` to insert text
5. Pasted in the previous contents of the file, using the old name and email that was working in the first place, and added the missing `#` from line 1 col 1.
6. Save and quit Vim `esc`, `:wq`

All seems to be working again!

Big thanks to everyone that jumped in via the comments!

Comment: Steps 1 to 4 (inclusive) are not required ;)